# Python: How do I load a buffer object of specific compressed files inside of a compressed file?

Tags: python, scipy, gzip, tarfile

I have a tar.bz2 with a list of specific .gz file(s) inside of it. After searching and finding the .gz file(s) within the tar.bz2, I want to load those specific .gz files to a buffer. I then want to decompress those loaded .gz file(s). Finally I want to load the decompressed .gz files as a .mat file. I would like do this without having to generate an external file.

Note: The .gz compressed file is only a single .mat file and not a further list of compressed files.

So to illustrate the compression architecture:
big_file.tar.bz2 -> cat.gz, dog.gz, hello.gz, hello1.gz
hello.gz -> hello (single .mat file)

The matching filename within the tar.bz2 is 'hello' as in files labeled as 'hello.gz', hello1.gz', ... etc.

My current problem is I'm having trouble getting the buffer format correct after the tar_bz2.extractfile().

The error from the snipet is at loadmat() as a seek to the end of the file issue, but I'm sure the source of my problems starts after tar_bz2.extractfile().

Here's what I have so far:

```
import tarfile
import gzip
from scipy.io import loadmat

def extract_mat_data(file):
    match_filename = 'hello'
    # Decompress tar.bz2
    mat_file_data = []
    with  tarfile.open(file,'r:bz2',errorlevel=1) as tar_bz2:
        # Loop over all the sub compressed files
        for file_ in tar_bz2:
            # Match only the files with the desired file name.
            if match_filename in file_.name:
                # Extract the match file into a buffer
                file_in_file = tar_bz2.extractfile(file_)
                # Extract the gz file from a buffer
                gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=file_in_file.fileobj,mode='rb')
                # Load the mat format buffer object
                single_mat_data = loadmat(gz)
                # Create a list with the mat data
                mat_file_data.append(single_mat_data)
    return mat_file_data

file = 'big_file.tar.bz2'
extract_mat_data(file)
```